# Sublimt text 3 - disable css color autocomplete

Tags: css, autocomplete, sublimetext3, disable

How to disable css hex color autocomplete in Sublime Text 3? I mean this:

[image]

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Please don't link to outside resources, including images, unless the pertinent information is also contained in the question itself. Links rot, and may not always be available for everyone. Including an image using the image tool on the question composition page ensures it will always be available.

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to the user settings for the Emmet package

```
"short_hex": false
```

Comment: Mec Os, unfortunnatly, it did not help (

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWugz.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPdUI.jpg

Comment: Check the standard settings on the left. Maybe i misspelled it. Should be there.

Comment: I didnt mean edit that file. I meant add that line to the user file. But the setting name should match that file.